# Can I refuse a 2nd drug test after "failing" The first from a doctor writing my medication

Tags: united-states, medical

I live in Virginia and I recently took a urine drug test my psychiatrist wanted because he was prescribing Valium. Came back that I had a different Benzodiazepine in my system that I have never been prescribed or ever taken. I do not use any illegal drugs or anything not prescribed to me. I searched for possible false positives in other medications that I'm taking but didn't find any. He said I will have to take a second random drug test in the near future.  Can I refuse the second test? What's the consequences of saying NO?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you won't get Valium. This is all part of your medical treatment, so its covered by [medical confidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_privacy#United_States).

Comment: I was told one more failed drug test and no other doctor would prescribe any controlled drugs cause this info is shared through the drug monitoring program.